# How can I use one to many in Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I created a project that I use two entities in it.
The first entity has two attributes and I called this entity Banks. In this I have title and cash.
The second has two attributes too and I called this entity Debits. In this I have title and cash.
How can I connect each Banks row to many Debits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's recommended to name entities in singular form, `Bank` and `Debit`.

- In the Core Data model add a relationship in entity `Bank`, *name* `debits`, *destination* `Debit`, select the Data Model inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘3</kbd>) and set *Type* to `To Many` and uncheck `Optional`
- Add a relationship in entity `Debit`, *name* `bank`, *destination* `Bank`, *Inverse* `debits`, in Data Model inspector set *Type* to `To One` and leave it `Optional`
- Go back to the `Bank` relationship and set *Inverse* to `bank`
- In the `Bank` class add

  ```
   @NSManaged public var debits: Set<Debit>
  ```
- In the `Debit` class add

  ```
   @NSManaged public var bank: Bank?
  ```